# Excel: Creating a dropdown using a list in another sheet?

Tags: excel

Let's say in Sheet1 I have a list of codes ("AA", "QF", etc).

In Sheet2, I want a particular column to have cells that, when you  click them, have a dropdown that consists of values from the code-list on Sheet1. (so you could fill the value of the cell with AA, QF, etc).

Is this doable?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes it is. Use Data Validation from the Data panel. Select Allow: List and pick those cells on the other sheet as your source.

Comment: Is there a way to make this data validation dropdown appear "automatically" for each cell in the column (except for the top header)?

Comment: Yes, just copy the cell to every other cell in the column. Alternatively, select the entire column before creating the data validation.

Comment: See my edit - just do the entire column. You can do this by clicking on the column hedder (The letter up on top) before clicking Data Validation and specifying your list.

Comment: For some reason the dropdowns disappear when I close/reopen Excel?

Comment: Are you saving your excel file?

Comment: Try saving it as a Macro-enabled workbook and let me know if this fixes the problem.

Comment: It appeared to be because I was saving as XLS -- saving as XLSX or XLSM works

Answer (score 21):

As cardern has said list will do the job.

Here is how you can use a named range.

Select your range and enter a new name:

[image: Select your range and enter a new name]

Select your cell that you want a drop down to be in and goto data tab -> data validation.

Select 'List' from the 'Allow' Drop down menu.

Enter your named range like this:

[image]

Now you have a drop down linked to your range.  If you insert new rows in your range everything will update automatically.

[image]

Comment: Does referencing to named range in another sheet really work with Excel 2007 too ?. I am getting an error "You cannot use references to other worksheets or workbooks for Data Validation criteria."

Comment: @user2143213 Sorry, I no longer have access to Excel 07' to verify and I'm not sure if it would work or not.  Good luck!

Comment: If you prefer to keep the source cells under the dropdown for ease of update. You can always select the rows & right click to hide them. This way it will be presentable and it's easy to update your source cells.

Comment: I can confirm that this method works in 2007 without a problem.

Answer (score 4):

That cannot be done in excel 2007. The list must be in the same sheet as your data.
It might work in later versions though.

Comment: This is the correct answer. It cannot be done as the OP asked it; the list data must be on the same sheet.

Comment: I am currently using excel 2007 and am using a named range on Sheet2 to do this very thing. This answer is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make this work by creating a named range in the current sheet that referred to the table I wanted to reference in the other sheet.

Answer (score -1):

Excel has a very powerful feature providing for a dropdown select list in a cell, reflecting data from a named region. It'a a very easy configuration, once you have done it before. Two steps are to follow:

```
Create a named region,
Setup the dropdown in a cell.
```

There is a detailed explanation of the process [HERE](http://www.milevis.com/Tips/Details/40).